# How to use this aggregate condition in golang mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

Ho can i write this condition in **golang** for **mongodb**:

```
success_count: { $sum: { $cond: ["$is_success", 1, 0] } }
```

I a'm trying this but not working:

```
"$success_count": bson.M{"$sum": bson.M{"$cond": bson.M{"$is_success", 1, 0}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]interface{}` instead of `bson.M`. Here `bson.M` is `map[string]interface{}` but you need to use slice.

```
bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{"$is_success", 1, 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [bson.A](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#A), which is just a representation of an Array.

```golang
bson.M{"$cond": bson.A{"$is_success", 1, 0}}
```